# OpenMP with nested loops

Tags: c++, openmp

I have few functions that should be applied to matrix of some structures serially. For single thread I use the following code:

```
for(int t = 0; t < maxT; ++t)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < maxI; ++i)
        for(int j = 0; j < maxJ; ++j)
            function1(i, j);

    for(int i = 0; i < maxI; ++i)
        for(int j = 0; j < maxJ; ++j)
            function2(i, j);
}
```

Now I'm trying to parallelize that code:

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
    for(int t = 0; t < maxT; ++t)
    {
        #pragma omp single
        function3(); // call this function once (once for each iteration of t)
        #pragma omp for
        for(int i = 0; i < sizeI; ++i)
            for(int j = 0; j < sizeJ; ++j)
                function1(i, j);

        #pragma omp for
        for(int i = 0; i < sizeI; ++i)
           for(int j = 0; j < sizeJ; ++j)
               function2(i, j);
    }
}
```

Is it correct?
Does it work it the way of reusing threads (not creating new threads team in main loop)?

Update: Explicit barrier is really unnecessary.

Actually, it seems that I was confused when I asked this question - the code example works properly. Now the question is: is it possible to call function (commented line in code) once after #pragma omp parrallel (not to call function3 in each thread in every iteration) . There is #pragma omp atomic to call increment operators and some others, but if I want to call a single instance of an arbitrary function (or, generally, to perform a block of code)?

Mark's comment. I assume that I will handle data races in my parallelized functions. The only question here is: stl containers are not simply thread safe when using OpenMP? i.e., if I want to push_back() in std::list from several threads I still need to lock that list manually.

Update 2: I've found that to run single action in parallel section it's needed to use #pragma omp single. So, this question is closed.

Comment: *Is it correct?*  Possibly.  Possibly not.  Your functions seem likely to operate through side effects.  Those side effects may implement data races ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this will create one parallel region where every thread will iterate `t` over the outer loop, and split up the work of the iterations of the `i` loops among the threads.

Note that a `#pragma omp for` has an implicit barrier at the end of it, so there is no need for you to also write your explicit barrier. This implicit barrier can be removed using the `nowait` clause (i.e. `#pragma omp for nowait`).